# Replacing character using JS /g function shows undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I'm using /g to replace characters in JS. It is not working.

It shows **undefined** when it should show the returned string.

```
function convert(str){
    var newStr = str.replace(/-/g , "_");
}
```

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: because `convert` is not returning anything. Add `return newStr` in the end.

Comment: @palaѕн I have tried that, it says illegal return statement.

Comment: can you show the code with return statement and the image also where it says, "_illegal return statement_"?

Comment: @palaѕн I have added it. Have a look

Comment: `return newStr` needs to be inside the `convert` function like `function convert(str){
    var newStr = str.replace(/-/g , "_");
    return newStr;
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: See it Works]It shows undefined because you have not returned anything from function convert(). This is a small modification to your code by adding return statement might help:)

```js
function convert(str){
    var newStr = str.replace(/-/g , "_");
    return newStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return your variable `newStr`

- Or can return `str.replace(/-/g , '_')` directly like this:

```js
const convert = str => str.replace(/-/g , '_')
const result = convert('this-is-a-text')

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't return anything. 
Try this code

```
function convert(str){
  var newStr = str.replace(/-/g , "_");
  return newStr;
}
```